# One() not working with AJAX?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have three div boxes on my pageIn each div box there is a delete button I press that removes the div box from the code. An ajax request in that same event sends an unique number based on which div box was pressed to the server. In order to prevent multiple click events to be called on the delete button, I used the one() event. But in rare events where I click the button quickly it will fire the event twice and I see that the database received duplicate numbers. I thought one() prevents that from happening. What could be wrong with my jquery code to cause it to fire twice? My code is below.

Sample button from HTML

```
<input id="delete_post_3" type="button" value="X">
```

jQuery Code

```
$('#delete_post_1').one('click', function() {
    var session_user_id = <? php echo $session_user_id; ?> ;
    var number = 1;
    $.post('ajax_delete_post.php', {
        user_id: session_user_id,
        number: number
    }, function() {
        $('#post_1').remove();
    });
});

$('#delete_post_2').one('click', function() {
    var session_user_id = <? php echo $session_user_id; ?> ;
    var number = 2;
    $.post('ajax_delete_post.php', {
        user_id: session_user_id,
        number: number
    }, function() {
        $('#post_2').remove();
    });
});

$('#delete_post_3').one('click', function() {
    var session_user_id = <? php echo $session_user_id; ?> ;
    var number = 3;
    $.post('ajax_delete_post.php', {
        user_id: session_user_id,
        number: number
    }, function() {
        $('#post_3').remove();
    });
});
```

Update: Per request, I'm going to give a brief explanation on my code for the entire page.

```
<script>

//when document is ready, loads jquery code that allows any div boxes that currently   
//exist on the page to have a click event that will delete the box. this is the same 
//code seen above in my example.

</script>

<form>
//form to fill out info
</form>

<script>
//ajax post sent when form button clicked
$.post('ajax_file.php', {data: data}, function(data){

//in here div box is created

<script>

//duplicated jquery code from top of page. without it the div box delete button does 
//not work

</script>

});

</script>
```

Comment: `undefined` I don't think `stopPropagation` applies to this because they are buttons, right ?

Comment: @aziz.punjani At first OP hadn't posted the markup.

Comment: jason, it shouldn't fire twice. How are you confirming that it was sent twice ? Do you see two ajax requests ?

Comment: Not to mention the fact that `.one()` uses a `$.Callback` object that can only be triggered once. It shouldn't be possible for the same one to be sent more than once with what has been posted in the question.

Comment: I'm checking the ajax requests now. But I do see it in the server that the same number was sent twice.

Comment: @jason328 Try adding a console.log to your click handlers then check that there are 2 calls or one!

Comment: Yep, it's showing multiple ajax requests. Again, let me say that this happens only if I press it quickly and it's rare. Still, it shouldn't be happening and I would like to know what's causing it.

Comment: Have you ensured that you are not calling `one` more than once for the same element?

Comment: Also, added `console.log('click')` below each `$('#delete_post_3').one('click', function() {` and see that I made six clicks when there should have only been three.

Comment: I can't reproduce it. even triggering 10 click events in a for loop which is near instant doesn't trigger it more than once. http://jsfiddle.net/xcwPe/ Chances are you are using `.one()` multiple times.

Comment: @jason328 Check your source to see if you have another set of same code. Right click -> View Source and find  `$('#delete_post_3').one('click'`

Comment: @Vega, I do have the same code multiple times in the source. It's because the div boxes are created from an ajax call so I had to put the same script code in the callback function for the ajax call that created the div box. How would I fix that then?

Comment: @jason328 Move it outside.. and you shouldn't duplicate your script code.. you can always bind event handler by delegating it to the container

Comment: Outside of the callback function? Wouldn't that cause the div boxes to not work with the javascript, especially since the replicated code needs to be called when the document is ready?

Comment: @jason328 When you do `$('#delete_post_2').one('click', function() {`, it will bind the handler function to the click event for `#delete_post_2`. When you duplicate the same line again, it will bind the handler function (new function but same code as there is no reference to old function) again to `#delete_post_2`. In such case, you have 2 handler function with same code bound to `#delete_post_2` and on click both will be executed **once**. What I meant is to move the script code outside of AJAX response so that it is not duplicated.

Comment: If that's the case then why is this error happening sporadically? I'm not trying to deride your answer, I just want to make sure I understand the error completely.

Comment: @jason328 Please explain the whole scenario on how it is getting duplicated. _It's because the div boxes are created from an ajax call so I had to put the same script code in the callback function for the ajax call that created the div box._  <<- I did not understand this part.

Comment: Update in question. Hopefully it will make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't tell if this issue is sorted or not, but given all the feedback in the comments it seems you are binding `one` twice and it also seems based on the comments you left in `user23875`'s answer that you are aware of that.

If you bind the event twice it executes twice, simple as that.

If you are fully aware of the fact that you are binding the event twice, why not try unbinding any previous attached event first.

```
$('#delete_post_1').off('click').one('click', function() {
...
$('#delete_post_2').off('click').one('click', function() {
...
$('#delete_post_3').off('click').one('click', function() {
```

Unless you are also re-rendering your complete HTML twice the above will make sure you are only ever having attached a single click event.

As `user23875` had pointed out, you are certainly doing something funky in your scripts.

You should be separating your code as much as possible to ensure code you only intent to run ones only gets called ones and so on.

Hopefully the above will fix this issue.

Comment: You are right on the dot. However, I have to have the javascript repeated in the ajax callback or the generated div box from the same ajax callback does not work. Unfortunately, I am no longer using the code and scraped it. Are you sure that .off() will work with removing .one()? The jquery documentation says it works for on.() but says nothing about .one(). If it does I'll give you credit.

Comment: @jason328: `off()` will remove the event handler from the specified event. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GxE5m/ Using `one()` the first button has 2 click events bound **without** using `off()` and as expected both get executed, the second button also has 2 click events bound using `one()` **with** `off()` and as expected only the second one is executed. Off course, when using namespaces for example `off("click.myNamespace").on("click.MyNamespace", function(){...})` only the events associated to the namespace are removed. any other events bound to just "click" would stay intact.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first check that you do not have a space between `<` and `php` where you echo the `session_user_id`... This might be an possible solution, the rest seams to be right.

Answer (score 0):

could you try this code and check the console if it fires twice?

```
$('#delete_post_3').on('click', function(event) {
    var session_user_id = <?php echo $session_user_id;?> ;
    var number = 3;
    $.post('ajax_delete_post.php', {
        user_id: session_user_id,
        number: number
    }, function() {
        $('#post_3').remove();
    })
    $(this).off(event);
})
```

### EDIT

try one last thing: quotes

```
"user_id": session_user_id,
"number": number
```

Comment: This would definitely fix the symptoms, but does it really fix the problem?

Comment: Actually, it didn't work. the unique number was sent twice. Thanks for the try though. And I would like to fix the problem since it appears to be a bigger issue.

Comment: @jason328 one last thing. try enclosing `user_id` and `number` in quotes. it might work.

Answer (score 0):

How about you add a `'.disabled'` class to the button on click, and have the click event have a `:not(.disabled)` on the event selector?

EXAMPLE:

`$('#delete_post_1:not(.disabled)').one('click', function() {
    $(this).addClass('disabled');
    var session_user_id = <? php echo $session_user_id; ?> ;
    var number = 1;
    $.post('ajax_delete_post.php', {
        user_id: session_user_id,
        number: number
    }, function() {
        $('#post_1').remove();
    });
});`

Comment: Here's your problem...

`<script>
//when document is ready, loads jquery code that allows any div boxes that currently   
//exist on the page to have a click event that will delete the box. this is the same 
//code seen above in my example.
</script>`

`//duplicated jquery code from top of page. without it the div box delete button does 
//not work
</script>
`

Comment: Basically, you're binding the event twice, it would seem.  Double-triple check to make sure this isn't happening.

Comment: I'm aware that the event is binding twice because I have the script run again after every ajax callback. Without it I can't run the code coming from the ajax callback. I would like to find an alternative way to not have to callback the duplicate javascript code, since that is tripping up the .one() event, but I have no idea how.

Comment: Just post a fiddle or something, you've got some funky ass code going on.  You need to not bind things on the AJAX callback, instead doing the logic you actually need.

Comment: I wish I could but I'm using ajax and ajax does not work well with fiddle. I'm rebuilding my database now and I think that will solve the problem since the code will be rewritten thus ridding me with the issue all together.

Comment: True facts.  It was just to see how the code was set up, I personally ran into a ton of issues when starting using AJAX calls myself.  If you want the truth though, I ended up hating jQuery's ajax functions.  I always go with FormData() and XMLHttpRequest()'s now.  Much easier to use and get their callbacks from vs jQuery's implementation.  Check MDN, those calls will someday save a (webdev's) life.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand in your document :

```
<script>
   //if #delete_post_1 exists in the page, it receives a "once" event handler to delete #post_1
</script>

<form>
</form>

<script>
$.post('ajax_file.php', {data: data}, function(data){
   //if the request succeeds, this html code is loaded into the DOM
<script>
       //are you sure that you do not bind a *second* "once" event handler to #delete_post_1 ?
</script>
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are using synchronous call issue. remove all the code from click function to a new function. call that function on click. also use asynchronous ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

You should lock your post and maybe get everything into one function like that:

```
            var locker = 0;
        $('.delete_post').on('click', function() {
        if (locker == 0)
        {
        locker = 1;
        var session_user_id = <? php echo $session_user_id; ?> ;
        var number = $(this).attr('id');
        $.post('ajax_delete_post.php', {
        user_id: session_user_id,
        number: number
        }, function() {
        $('#'+number).remove();
        locker = 0
        });
        }
        });
```

Your input thing should of course look like that then:

```
<input id="3" class="delete_post" type="button" value="X">
 <input id="2" class="delete_post" type="button" value="X">
  <input id="1" class="delete_post" type="button" value="X">
```

Answer (score 0):

Stop binding the events every time you add more buttons and instead bind them only once using event delegation.

```
var session_user_id = <? php echo $session_user_id; ?> ;
$("#someparentelement").on( "click", "button[id^=delete_post]:not(.handled)", function(){
    var theid = this.id.replace(/delete_post_/i,"");
    $(this).addClass("handled");
    $.post('ajax_delete_post.php', {
        user_id: session_user_id,
        number: theid
    }, function() {
        $('#post_' + theid).remove();
    });
});
```

Small note though, I suspect you don't need to pass `user_id`, php should be able to pull that out of the session.

Edit: Oops, `.one` delegeated still only fires one event overall, not one per child. Updated to similar `.on` functionality.

http://jsfiddle.net/JPULH/

**Important**
Do not put this code in a location where it will execute more than once.

Answer (score 0):

I know your question was about finding out why your one() wasn't working. But it looks like, over the course of discussion, we've all determined that you've ended up creating multiple one() declarations. We also now know that you'll get one execute for each one() you declare and that is undesired for your situation. While that finding technically answers your question, I believe your problem isn't solved.  I was thinking that maybe your approach to your problem could be modified and ended up making this JS fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/sEvAn/45/

The gist of my suggestion:

1. Bind your click event to the OUTER div wrapper ("#post_list" in my example). This allows you to always detect delete button clicks, even if a post was newly created/added to your DOM via an ajax call.
2. Include a custom data-postid attribute on each of your buttons to make it easy to determine which post ID you need to delete.
3. In my example, I use a slow fadeOut to simulate a slow ajax call. But the point of that is to show how to use the completion callback function to do something else (like remove the DOM element that's been successfully deleted.

That's pretty much it. This is my first attempt ever to answer a question on stackoverflow, so I hope you'll find this helpful!